# Java program that adds two numbers generated by using two sliders

Tags: java, swing, sliders

I have this assignment for my java class where I must add two numbers using sliders, and I'm really stuck. Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener; 
import javax.swing.*;

public class slideCalculator {
JButton add,subtract;
JSlider num1st,num2nd;
JLabel answer;
public slideCalculator(){
    JFrame calc = new JFrame("Mediocre Calculator");
    num1st = new JSlider (0, 100, 0);
    num1st.setMajorTickSpacing (10);
    num1st.setMinorTickSpacing (5);
    num2nd = new JSlider (0, 100, 0);
    num2nd.setMajorTickSpacing (10);
    num2nd.setMinorTickSpacing (5);
    add = new JButton("+");
    subtract = new JButton("-");
    answer = new JLabel("");
    calc.setDefaultCloseOperation(calc.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    calc.setVisible(true);
    calc.setBounds(500, 200, 290, 210);
    calc.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,2,1,1));
    calc.add(new JLabel("First Number: "));
    calc.add(num1st);
    calc.add(new JLabel("Second Number: "));
    calc.add(num2nd);
    calc.add(new JLabel("Answer: "));
    calc.add(answer);
    calc.add(add);
    calc.add(subtract);
    add.addActionListener(new action());
    subtract.addActionListener(new action());

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    slideCalculator lc = new slideCalculator();
}
public class action implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        int firstNum = Integer.parseInt(num1st.getValue());
        int secondNum = Integer.parseInt(num2nd.getValue());
        if(ae.getValue()== add){
            answer.setText(String.valueOf(firstNum+secondNum));
        }
        else if (ae.getValue()==subtract){
            answer.setText(String.valueOf(firstNum-secondNum));
        }
        } 

}
}
```

When I go to run it it does not want to work. I'm probably missing something but I can't seem to figure it out. Am I even correct on any of it?

Comment: *"it does not want to work"* It would help if you tell why. Do you get errors? The output is not what you expect?

Comment: Post edited: No need to bash your teacher as the responsibility for learning this subject is yours and yours alone, regardless of your teacher "doing a bad job".

Answer (score 5):

This:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    int firstNum = Integer.parseInt(num1st.getValue());
    int secondNum = Integer.parseInt(num2nd.getValue());
    if(ae.getValue()== add){  // *****
```

makes no sense. Shoot -- it doesn't even compile since ActionEvent's don't have a `getValue()` method. You don't get the ActionEvent's "value" but rather you get its actionCommand String via `getActionCommand()`, and then you can compare it with other Strings using String's `equals(...)` or `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method.

i.e.,

```
if ("+".equals(ae.getActionCommand()) {
   // do addition
} else if ("-".equals(ae.getActionCommand()) {
   // do subtraction
}
```

In future questions, please post all compiler errors that occur if you get any.

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 sources of compilation error here.

[JSlider#getValue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSlider.html#getValue%28%29) returns an `int` value so there's no need to use `Integer.parseInt` which expects a `String`. Instead you can use:

```
int firstNum = num1st.getValue();
int secondNum = num2nd.getValue();
```

Also `getValue` is undefined for `ActionEvent`, `getSource` will give you the `Object` reference for the `JButton`:

```
Object source = ae.getSource();
if (ae.getSource() == add) {
   answer.setText(String.valueOf(firstNum + secondNum));
} else if (source == subtract) {
   answer.setText(String.valueOf(firstNum - secondNum));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener; 
import javax.swing.*;

public class slideCalculator {
JButton add,subtract;
JSlider num1st,num2nd;
JLabel answer;
public slideCalculator(){
    JFrame calc = new JFrame("Mediocre Calculator");
    num1st = new JSlider (0, 100, 0);
    num1st.setMajorTickSpacing (10);
    num1st.setMinorTickSpacing (5);
    num2nd = new JSlider (0, 100, 0);
    num2nd.setMajorTickSpacing (10);
    num2nd.setMinorTickSpacing (5);
    add = new JButton("+");
    subtract = new JButton("-");
    answer = new JLabel("");
    calc.setDefaultCloseOperation(calc.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    calc.setVisible(true);
    calc.setBounds(500, 200, 290, 210);
    calc.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,2,1,1));
    calc.add(new JLabel("First Number: "));
    calc.add(num1st);
    calc.add(new JLabel("Second Number: "));
    calc.add(num2nd);
    calc.add(new JLabel("Answer: "));
    calc.add(answer);
    calc.add(add);
    calc.add(subtract);
    add.addActionListener(new action());
    subtract.addActionListener(new action());

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    slideCalculator lc = new slideCalculator();
}
public class action implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        int firstNum = num1st.getValue();
        int secondNum = num2nd.getValue();
        if("+".equals(ae.getActionCommand())) {
            answer.setText(String.valueOf(firstNum+secondNum));
        }
        else 
        if ("-".equals(ae.getActionCommand())) {
            answer.setText(String.valueOf(firstNum-secondNum));
        }
        } 

}
}
```